# Why Azure Front Door is required while using third party WAF for custom domain in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, akamai, azure-front-door, web-application-firewall

I was trying to implement custom domains for Azure AD B2C, so that when a user tries to login/register into my application,they should not be displayed with a URL .b2clogin.com instead should use my custom domain

While going through the MS Docs for this requirement, [(Refer here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow) they recommend to use Azure Front Door, but they also allow to use third party WAF such as Akamai.([Refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow#can-i-use-a-third-party-web-application-firewall-waf-with-b2c))

[Can use Third Party WAF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENJar.jpg)

and Here the documentation ([Refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/partner-akamai)) says that Azure Front Door is required even if we bring in a third party WAF.
[Azure Front Door as a Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UBXw.jpg)

The question is why here Azure Front Door is required ? Is there anything special Azure AD B2C Requires?

Answer (score 1):

AFD and AAD B2C services are doing some behind the scenes things to make it work. One of those things is adjusting how cookies are set. Hence it is required.